# Transferring PuTTY session data

Tags: putty

My Windows NT account name was changed, and when starting [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) it now appears that my saved session information has been lost.

The [FAQ](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-settings) suggests that PuTTY sessions should be stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY`.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#HKEY_CURRENT_USER_.28HKCU.29) explains that HKCU maps to `NTUSER.DAT` and `USRCLASS.DAT` under the current user's `Desktop and Settings` folder.

I still have these files for my old account name, but I'm guessing there is no easy way to extract data from these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described by [this Microsoft TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759303%28WS.10%29.aspx) you can load a `.dat` file into an existing registry:

> **To load a hive into the registry**
>
> 1. Open Registry Editor.
> 2. In the registry tree (on the left), click either the HKEY_USERS or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE keys.
> 3. On the File menu, click Load Hive.
> 4. In Look in, click the drive, folder, or network computer and folder that contains the hive you want to load.
> 5. Click Open.
> 6. In Key Name, type the name that you want to assign to the hive, and then click OK.

You can then browse the tree and export the PuTTY configuration from

```
HKCU or HKLM\Entered Key Name\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY
```

For the bit where you want to add the old registry settings into your new registry. Before using 'File > Import' to import your .reg file, do the following (I did this on my Windows XP machine and it worked)

- Open your saved .reg file in an editor
- Replace all occurences of 'HKCU or HKLM\Entered Key Name' with 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER' so that the reg paths look like the following:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham]
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY]
  ```

  etc.

Comment: And just FYI, you will need to Unload the hive in order to get it out of the registry after loading it.  Just click on the loaded hive then select **File** -> **Unload Hive**.  That one took me a second to figure out as the error message when you try to delete the loaded hive root key is not very useful.

Comment: Aha - and an extra point for the Unload Hive tip :-)

Answer (score 1):

Export only putty data from regedit:

```
regedit /e "%userprofile%\desktop\putty.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham
```

On your target PC right click on the putty.reg file and merge.

---

**To transfer it to `PuTTY portable`**

`PuTTY portable` configs are stored in `PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\`. Simply moving exported `putty.reg` to `PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\` do not work. PuTTY Portable backup the file and create a new empty one.

To workaround this issue, merge both `putty.reg` copying manually the config you want to migrate from your exported `putty.reg` to the newly created `PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\putty.reg` below following lines.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY]
"RandSeedFile"="D:\\Programme\\PuTTYPortable\\Data\\settings\\PUTTY.RND"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can quickly and easily be accomplished through command line.

Bring up the command prompt window by clicking the Start Menu in the task bar or pressing the Windows key, then type `cmd` and press enter.

Navigate to the directory you desire to save the file to. For example, to save it to the current user's Desktop, type `cd Desktop` and press enter.

Now export the PuTTY registry information by entering the following:

```
REG EXPORT HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY PuTTY.reg
```

To import the data, use `cmd` again and navigate with `cd` to the location of the `PuTTY.reg` file and enter:

```
REG IMPORT PuTTY.reg
```

Note that these entries are all case sensitive.